# How to write n number of loops mathematically

Tags: notation, computer-science

I have the following code. I want to write it mathematically. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int in1=1, in2=-1;
double totalDistance=0.0;
double min_dis = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for(int i=0;i<N1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<N2;j++){
        dis = calculateDistance(Solutions(i),Solutions(j));
                totalDistance = dis;
                if(totalDistance< min_dis){
                    min_dis=totalDistance;
                    in1=i;
                    in2=j;
            }   
        }
    }
print(in1, in2)
```

Mathematically, I write it as follows:
\begin{equation}
argmin_{i,j \in \{1,2, \dots, n_1\} \times \{1,2, \dots, n_2\}} dis(S_i, S_j)
\end{equation}
$\times$ refers to Cartesian product between sets and ${dis(S_i, S_j)}$ is the distance.

I want to know is it correct mathematical representation. If it is correct, I want to extend it to *n* loops. Following is an example of *3* loops.

```
int in1=1, in2=-1, in3=-1;
    double totalDistance=0.0;
    double min_dis = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0;i<N1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N2;j++){
            double dis1 = calculateDistance(**S1**(i), **S2**(j));
            for(int z=0;z<N3;z++){
                double dis2 = calculateDistance(**S2**(j), **S3**(z));
                totalDistance = dis1+ dis2;
                if(totalDistance< min_dis){
                    min_dis=totalDistance;
                    in1=i;
                    in2=j;
                    in3=z;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(in1 in2 in3);
```

How can I represent the generalized version in mathematical notation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical expression is not correct. Here we focus on the first code snippet. The consideration for the second part and the general case is similarly.

> Some aspects need to be considered in more detail:
>
> - There may be more than one pair with minimum distance, while the code returns always a single element.
> - The *order* of the for-loops: This is important in case there are more than one element with minimum distance.
> - Technical detail: The index range is $0\leq i < N$ instead of  $1\leq i\leq N$.

In the following we use the notation
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{calculateDistance(Solutions(i),Solutions(j))}\quad&\longrightarrow\quad d(S_i,S_j)\\
\operatorname{N1}\quad&\longrightarrow\quad N_1\\
\operatorname{N2}\quad&\longrightarrow\quad N_2\\
\operatorname{in1}\quad&\longrightarrow\quad i_1\\
\operatorname{in2}\quad&\longrightarrow\quad i_2\\
\end{align*}

> **First step: $2$ loops**
>
> Let $N_1,N_2>0$. We obtain,    assuming symmetry of the distance function
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_2&:={\operatorname{argmin}}_{0\leq i_2<i_1<\max\{N_{i_1},N_{i_{2}}\}}\{d(S_{i_1},S_{i_2})\}\\
> &=\{(i_1,i_2):d(S_{i_1},S_{i_2})\leq d(S_{j_1},S_{j_2}),0\leq i_1,j_1<N_1, 0\leq i_2,j_2<N_2\}\\
> \\
> B_2&:=\min_{0\leq i_2<N_2}\min_{0\leq i_1<N_1}\{(i_1,i_2):(i_1,i_2)\in A_2\}
> \end{align*}
>   with $B_2$ consisting of the one element which is returned by the code.

There may be more than one pair with the same minimum distance, so that $A_2$ will contain usually more than one element. Assume
the set $A_2$ contains the four elements
\begin{align*}
A_2=\{(4,3),(4,5),(8,2),(10,6)\}
\end{align*}
In this case the code will return $(4,3)$. Since $4$ is the smallest value of the first coordinates, the candidates from $A_2$ are $(4,3)$ and $(4,5)$. Out of these two values the code selects the one with the lowest second coordinate giving $(4,3)$.

This implies that the *order* of the minimum settings in $B_2$ is essential. Note that
\begin{align*}
B_2=&\min_{0\leq k_2<N_2}\min_{0\leq k_1<N_1}\{(k_1,k_2):(k_1,k_2)\in A_2\}=\{(4,3)\}\quad\text{while}\\
&\min_{0\leq k_1<N_1}\min_{0\leq k_2<N_2}\{(k_1,k_2):(k_1,k_2)\in A_2\}=\{(8,2)\}\\
\end{align*}

> **General step: $k$ loops**
>
> Let $N_1,N_2,\ldots,N_k>0,k\geq 2$. We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_k&:={\displaystyle{{\text{argmin}}_{{0\leq i_l<i_{l+1}<\max\{N_{i_l},N_{i_{l+1}}\}}\atop{1\leq l\leq k-1}}}
> \left\{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}d(S_{i_j},S_{i_{j+1}})\right\}}\\
> \\
> B_k&:=\min_{0\leq i_k<N_k}\min_{0\leq i_{k-1}<N_{k-1}}
> \cdots\min_{0\leq i_1<N_1}\{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k):(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k)\in A_k\}
> \end{align*}
>   with $B_k$ consisting of the one element which is returned by the code.

*Code review:*

- $\operatorname{in1}$ should be initialised with $-1$
- Since both indices $i$ an $j$ are the argument for the call $\operatorname{calculateDistance(S(i),S(j))}$ and the call is symmetrical with respect to the arguments it is not sound, that $i$ and $j$ have different range. We would rather assume
  \begin{align*}
  &0\leq i_1,i_2< N_1\\
  \end{align*}
- We expect a *distance function* $d$ to act symmetrically: $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ for all $x,y$ and also $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x$. So, we would rather code
  \begin{align*}
  &0\leq i_2 < i_1<N_1\\
  \end{align*}

Comment: What you are suggesting that I should write the mathematical expression in two phases as you did for first code snippet. However, I need to write the expression for n number of loops, I mean in generalized form.

@Code review: For my case, I can not assume that $0\leq i_1, i_2 <N$, they can have different size.

Comment: @Md.ShahriarMahbub: A two step description seems to be convenient. I can add a generalized version if needed. But first of all a question to the *distance* function. Is it symmetrical, i.e. $d(S_i,S_j)=d(S_j,S_i)$ and $d(S_i,S_i)=0$ for all $i,j$? In that case you should be able to code it as $N:=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and iterate in two for-loops according to $0\leq i_2 <i_1<N$.

Comment: It would be good, if you provide a generalized version. Please consider solutions are taken from different solution set (please see second code snippet). yes it is symmetrical for my case. 



*Iterate in two for-loops according to $0 \leq i_2 < i_1 < N$*, is this case, do you consider, $N_1>N2$ ?

Comment: @Md.ShahriarMahbub: I will provide a generalised version after work in the evening. One aspect which could be helpful for your coding. If you have to consider different $N_1,N_2,\ldots,N_k$ and you take pairwise limits in each for-loop, you could implement it as $0\leq i_2<i_1<\max\{N_1,N_2\}; 0\leq i_3<i_2<\max\{N_2,N_3\}; \ldots ;0\leq i_k<i_{k-1}<\max\{N_{k-1},N_k\}$.

Comment: @Md.ShahriarMahbub: General case added. Regards,

Comment: This solution is not correct since it does not enforce integrality of the indices, and the set $B_k$ is based on minimizing vectors without defining an order on vectors.

Comment: The for-loops define $i$ and $j$ to be integer. Your answer doesn't.

The innermost minimization in $B_k$ is $\min_{0\leq i_1 < N_1} \{ (i_1,i_2) : (i_1,i_2) \in A_2 \}$. This is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Define the set of minimizers:

$S = \arg\min_{ x \in \mathbb{N}^n} \{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} dis(S_{x_i},S_{x_{i+1}}) : x_i < n_i \; i = 0,1,\ldots,n-2 \}$

The solution is the lexicographic first element of $S$:

$\min\{x \in S \}$

where $\min$ performs lexicographic minimization. This returns the same element of $S$ that your code outputs.

Comment: Many thanks. Can you please help me to interpret the notation you suggest. Are you presenting x as index? Means $dis(S_{x_i}, S_{x_{i+1}})$? With your proposed notation, how can I show indices are the Cartesian product. @LinAlg

Comment: Your $i$ and $j$ are my $x_1$ and $x_2$. For the remainder it's just basic set notation.

Comment: With your proposed notation, how can I show indices are the Cartesian product. I mean all the combinations. is $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ means that? So, the equation becomes $\arg\min_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \{ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} dis(S_{x_i},S_{x_{i+1}}) : x_i < n_i \; i = 1,2,\ldots,n-1 \}$

Comment: Right! $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why not ${ x \in \mathbb{N}^n}$, $\mathbb{N}$ refer to natural number set.

Comment: Makes sense, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need the colon or anything after it.

Comment: @LinAlg Considering the changes I have made (enclosed in ** in the algorithm, the solutions come from different set), can I write it as follows: $\arg\min_{ l \in \mathbb{N}^n} \Big\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} dis(S_i^{l_i},S_{i+1}^{l_{i+1}}) : l_i < n_i \; i = 1,2,\ldots,n-1 \Big\}$

Comment: that's correct!